# Mysql get unique entries with two left joins

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

I have the following mysql query, which is producing a list of entries by category. However, some of the entries produced are duplicates (duplicate entry_id - because they appear in more than one category). How can ensure there are no duplicates? I have attempted to use other variations of `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`, but without success. Thank you.

```
SELECT ct.entry_id, ct.title, c.cat_name
FROM exp2_categories c
LEFT JOIN exp2_category_posts cp ON (cp.cat_id = c.cat_id)
LEFT JOIN exp2_channel_titles ct ON (ct.entry_id = cp.entry_id) 
WHERE c.group_id = '4' 
GROUP BY c.cat_id
ORDER BY ct.entry_date DESC
```

**EDIT:**

The first answer is great, except it produces multiple entries per category. I need one unique entry per category. Sorry, I should have been more specific in my original question.

For example, what it produces -
Entries are unique, but there are too many entries:

```
entry_id_1    Title 1    Category_1, Category_2
entry_id_3    Title 3    Category_2
entry_id_345  Title 345  Category_3
entry_id_123  Title 123  Category_4, Category_3, Category_1
entry_id_678  Title 678  Category_4
```

**Desired result** -
Entries are unique and there is only one entry per category:

```
entry_id_1    Title 1    Category_1
entry_id_3    Title 3    Category_2
entry_id_345  Title 345  Category_3
entry_id_123  Title 123  Category_4
```

Comment: Please post an example of the tables, and an example of the result you are getting from this query

Comment: What happens when you use group by ct.entry_id...

Comment: When I use group by ct.entry_id, I get unique entries but repeated categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting "duplicates" is that you are selecting category too, so if an entry is in multiple categories, you'll get multiple rows.

What need is the [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```
SELECT ct.entry_id, ct.title, group_concat(c.cat_name) as cat_names
FROM exp2_categories c
LEFT JOIN exp2_category_posts cp ON (cp.cat_id = c.cat_id)
LEFT JOIN exp2_channel_titles ct ON (ct.entry_id = cp.entry_id) 
WHERE c.group_id = '4' 
GROUP BY ct.entry_id, ct.title
ORDER BY ct.entry_date DESC
```

This will create one row for each entry, with a comma delimited list of categories it's in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is great, except it produces multiple entries per category - sorry, I should have been more specific in my question. I have amended my question.

Comment: I can help you, but I need to know: Do you care *which* category is chosen when there are multiple matches? eg for `entry_id_1, Title 1, Category_1, Category_2` do you care if you get `Category_1` or `Category_2`? If you care, how do you want to decide?

Comment: I don't care which category is chosen for each entry, as long as the end result contains all the categories (one entry each), without repeating a category or an entry. I hope I"m making sense?

Comment: You're making sense (just), but it can't be done in a query because the category chosen for each entity depends on *all* the rows that have been output already, and SQL can't do that. You'll need some application code to process the rows and do this for you.